# How to use secrets stored in harshicorp in my curl request

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am new to Harshicorp vault

--> my requirement is store the user name and password as secret 
--> then that secretes I should use it in my curl command

is this possible in Harshicorp vault , if yes please let me know how to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first best starting point should be the [Hashicorp website](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/index.html), then the [API documents](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2.html). This will provide you enough information on how to use the API as curl request.

However, I am providing starting commands to you to know that yes this is achievable,

to store credentials using vault cli, you would need token, VAULT_URL to be exported

```
export VAULT_ADDR=https://my-vault.company.com
export VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true #if certificate are self-signed 
export VAULT_TOKEN=MYTOKEN_WHICH_IS_SUPER_IMPORTANT

vault write secret/mysuperuberrandomsecret \
            username="hashicorp" \
            password="fse578468hdfkbsyrt36t44y8748745$^%$"
```

to read using curl, you would need approle/token and VAULT URL obviously

```
#Request
curl -k \
       --header "X-Vault-Token: MYTOKEN_WHICH_IS_SUPER_IMPORTANT" \
       https://my-vault.company.com/v1/secret/mysuperuberrandomsecret 

#Response
{
  "request_id": "a75d9bfa-XXXX-XXXXX-XXX-dbc72c5d7850",
  "lease_id": "",
  "renewable": false,
  "lease_duration": 604800,
  "data": {
    "password": "fse578468hdfkbsyrt36t44y8748745$^%$",
    "username": "hashicorp"
  },
  "wrap_info": null,
  "warnings": null,
  "auth": null
}
```

In the data section, you can see the username and password that was stored before;
Hope this helps